# how to activate openssl extension on php8.0/php8.1?

Tags: php

Iwas downloaded composer via

> sudo apt-get install composer

and then I check it

> composer --version

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20210902/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

i was check `php -i | grep -i openssl` and that was result

> OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)

I have changed my php.ini file in /etc/php/8.0/php.ini, I was uncomment the  and change the '

> 'extension=ssl'

and changed

> extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902"

but that's not effect anything.

how should I do sensei :"v?

Comment: Make sure you restart httpd after updating the php settings

Comment: how to do that? I see that httpd.service not found on me

Comment: what server are you running? and what platform? are you using xampp or wamp?

Comment: Please consult your system operations manual and also your teams developer manual on how to configure PHP extensions. This can greatly vary depending for and in which environment. Basically what @Mashtan commented, you need to share a couple more details to find the relevant Q&A material on site.